# React Native - Modal as an Error Component (opening multiple times)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I create an Error component to show in a modal.
I also use PubSub to get notifications of Errors, so then I cat activate the Component.

But, I have multiple screens, like Sign In, Sign Up, Whatever Form, Another Form.

Thus, everytime I have an  component, it builds a new one... So depending on the screen you're at, you can get up to 5 models opening with the same message.

- If you are in Sign In, then you have just one modal - It self
- If you are in Sign Up you have two - Sign In and It self
- If you are in Whatever Form you have three: Sign In, Sign Up (if you entered that screen) and It Self

....

And it goes on.

So the class is pretty simple.

```
export default class Error extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalVisible: false,
      errors: []
    }

    this.setModalVisible = this.setModalVisible.bind(this);
  }

  setModalVisible(visible) {
    this.setState({modalVisible: visible});
  }

  // Using pubSub to get new error msgs...    
  componentDidMount() {
    PubSub.subscribe("error",function(topic,error){
          // Did this to try to stop to show twice
          if(this.state.modalVisible)
            return;

          //Irelevant code here    
          this.setState({errors: errors});

          this.setModalVisible(true);
      }.bind(this));
  }


  render() {
    return (    
      <Modal
        animationType={"slide"}
        transparent={false}
        visible={this.state.modalVisible}
        onRequestClose={() => this._setModalVisible(false)}
        >
       <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.header}>
              <View/>
              <Text style={styles.headerText}>
                An error has occured
              </Text>

               <Icon
                raised
                name='close'
                color='red'
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible)
                }} />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.errorContainer}>
            { this.state.errors.map((error, index) => <Text key={index} style={styles.error}>{error}</Text> ) }
          </View>

       </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

I have an "ViewContainer" with general apperence for my app (like the header, and backbutton). And I render  there. But every screen I render it like this:

```
  render(){
    return (
      <ViewContainer title={'Awesome Form Here'} onBackPress={ this.back }>
        //Content goes here
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
```

So the real question is: How to make sure that react (or react-native) wont create a bunch of this component... How can I garantee one per screen and not have all of them pop up?

PS: I guess I can add an attribute to the Error component... with like:

```
{
   screen: "Awesome Form",
   error: "Errors here"
}
```

And on my Subscribe method I check if I should make it visible based on the screen name. Something like:

```
if(!this.state.screenName == error.screen)
  return;
```

Any way, this looks too primative. Maybe there's a better way.

**EDIT** To use the component:

```
    <Error />
```

And use PubSub to submit errors:

```
  PubSub.publish("error", json.errors || ['Something went wrong.']);
```

Comment: So every time you get an error, it pops up the current error along with any previous errors? On a side note, I think you have a typo here this._setModalVisible(false) in your onRequestClose.

Comment: Also can you provide some code on how you're using your Error component?

Comment: Thanks Matt, I updated the question :) And no, it doesnt upload previous errors... It pop's ALL Error components that were mounted on previous screens. 

So Sign In -> Sign Up -> Form 1 -> Form 2 -> Form 3

If you navigate through all of those Views, it will pop up 5 Modals with the same error. (Because every <Error /> creates a new instance... And ALL instances "watch" the error channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, like I said on the question... I've done this ugly solution: I'm still looking for better alternatives.

```
      // Checking if the screen is the same
      if(this.props.screen !== error.screen)
        return;
```

Building the error object:

```
  var error = {
    screen: 'SignIn',
    errors: json.errors || ['Something went wrong.']
  }

  PubSub.publish("error", error);
```

And using the Error component:

```
    <Error screen='SignUp'/>
```